# How to run activity without showing it?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, background

I have an activity (A) and activity (B). A is responsible for loading information, and B is the main activity. In B there are also loading operations which are realted to the UI (listeners, for example). I want to show activity A, and run activity B, but I want that B will be shown only when the loading (of B) was finished (I have a ProgressDialog in A).
How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: I believe that you can't load the UI if it's not being shown or rendered, I would put the `ProgressDialog` in activity B while it's loading instead of on the first one

Comment: It sounds to me that the tasks of A are more suitable to a thread than an Activity.

Comment: @SatelliteSD That's the solution, and it made the loading of my application much faster. Thanks!

Comment: added my comment as answer, so you can accept it (or Mus's, since it is basically the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me that the tasks of A are more suitable to a thread than an Activity.

Answer (score 0):

This seems more of an architecture problem. You might want to reconsider using two activities. You can use AsyncTask in a single activity to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fragments to achieve what you want!
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
Cit: "However, a fragment is not required to be a part of the activity layout; you may also use a fragment without its own UI as an invisible worker for the activity."
If you use the support library you dont have to worry about your SDK target.